# write a php to output the query result of friends who's friends with user id is 2

Tags: php, mysql

I have two column table friends table where it has a recode of users whos friends with eacho other. i want to get a list who's friends with a specific user. to do that i wrote a sql query as such and got a result..

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `friends` 
WHERE  `user_idf` =  '2'
OR  `user_idff` =  '2'

++ user_idf ++++   user_idff+++
    2   +   1
    3   +   2   
    4   +   2
    2   +   5
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

how to write a php function to echo user who's a friend of 2 (this i will replace with a POST where it gets user id from an application)
i.e.
1, 3, 4, 5

Comment: what do you need to know about the php function? Why aren't you doing a Union as per my original answer.  If you dont do the union then PHP has to do the extra work of looking through each row to determine which column represents the user and which represents the friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you mean something like this?

```
(SELECT `user_idf` FROM `user` WHERE `user_idff` = 2) UNION (SELECT `user_idff` FROM `user` WHERE `user_idf` = 2)
```

Im not great with sql to be honest, but I think union is what you are looking for (and I think my syntax is correct although im not 100%).

This **should** from my understanding take the user ids of anyone who is friends with user 2 and output it. The union of results returned when user 2 is in `user_idf` and `user_idff` columns.

EDIT:  Actually I still stand by my answer, if you don;t do this sql side then you will have to have a more complex PHP function.

For the PHP itself look into mysqli and PDO as your two main options for prepared statements.

Comment: yap i admit that your answer was the answer i was looking for mate... thnx alot. :)

Comment: by taking that answer can i use it like 

sql1 = SELECT * FROM `user_details` WHERE user_id = ((SELECT `user_idf` FROM `friends` WHERE `user_idff` = 2) UNION (SELECT `user_idff` FROM `friends` WHERE `user_idf` = 2)); ??? i know its wrong but how to write it correctly?